# Is it possible to increase someone else's bounty?

Tags: discussion

I found a question recently I want to put a bounty on, but it already has one. Is there a way for me to increase their bounty or do I have to wait until theirs is done to do my own?

Comment: Why do you want to increase it? a 500 rep bounty item gets the same visibility as a 50 point one. (The higher bounty might help it get an answer I guess, but that's no guarantee at all).

Comment: I want to increase it because I think it's a good question. I know it doesn't increase the visibility, but it might be incentive for more people to send in some answers. I'd be more likely to answer a 500 point bounty question as opposed to a 50 point bounty question, you know?